# Why target bones doesn't move the knee?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm trying to rig my model, but I struggle with it so much. I added target bones for my knees, but when I'm trying to move them, leg doesn't seem to follow the movement. As if they weren't connected, but I don't know where's the issue. Could anyone possibly help? I'm using Blender 4.0 by the way and I used rigify to generate the rig.[image]

[image][image]

EDIT: Here are more examples to illustrate my issue. I was following a tutorial and that's how it looks in the video:
[image]

As you can see knee goes a bit backwards, when you move a target pole.

[image]
While in my file, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: They're pole targets.  The control the direction the knee points, not the location of the knee, and you're moving it only in the direction the knee already points.  To change the position of the knee, move the IK target (shin.001.R if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: Rigify's metarig is supposed to be used as a placement tool to generate a full-featured rig. You are not supposed to use the metarig as an actual rig and manually build other things on top of it.

Comment: Hey, thank you all for your answers, @moonboots here's a file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gb0YeWPe" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gb0YeWPe/).

Comment: @Nathan I was following the tutorial where knee was following the movement, when the author moved pole target. I'll post a reference to explain further what my point is.

Comment: @L0Lock, so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing bend the knees a bit in *Edit* mode, otherwise it won't know how to bend once in *Pose* mode:

[image]

Also give the IK bones a *Chain Length* of 2 so that they only influence 2 bones: itself plus the thigh:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works, you helped a lot.